# cpanel Warning: Your system administrator must enable shell access to allow you to view clone URLS

Tags: git, shell, cpanel

I am trying to connect GitHub repo with Cpanel so I can work locally form the VSC form my PC and when I push the code to GitHub it automatically uploads the code to Cpanel in the tutorials they git a clone URL but I don't get it, it says must enable shell access to allow you to view clone but even after I made ssh key nothing changes.

Comment: The warning said: `Warning: Your system administrator must enable shell access to allow you to view clone URLS.` You have to contact sys admin to enable it.

Comment: @Nurkartiko alright thanks for the help :D

Comment: it was the first time for me using panel so I wasn't really familiar with all options and again thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to contact your host to enable shell access to you.